# Scrolling in listview by two touches instead one

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with the Scroll ListView.
It's so weird, scrolling works only with two fingers instead of one. 
Looks like the first touch is select ListView, second touch is to scroll.

On the layout there editText, which is initially at startup activity was the focus. I changed it, but scroll does not work anyway.

Maybe need to set the focus of the ListView in the code?

My layout

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:background="#eeeeee"

    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"

        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/search_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:singleLine="true"

        />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Событие"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"


            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Место"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventListView"
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"

        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

ListItem layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/photoimg"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/datetext"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titletext"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titletext"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titletext" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/titletext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoimg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/locationtext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datetext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/favbtn"
        android:src="@mipmap/star"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/locationtext"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/likebtn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/likebtn"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/likebtn"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@mipmap/like"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/favbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't suppose you have TalkBack enabled?

Answer (score 0):

`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Remove this.

---

Romain Guy wrote [a post in 2008](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/touch-mode.html) explaining what touch mode is.

Focused views will receive key (as in keyboard) events from the system. One view can be focused at a time.

It often doesn't make sense to make your views focusable in touch mode. There are exceptions like EditText, where you can consider the case of multiple EditTexts on screen, and wanting to specify which one should be typed in.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! But still doesn't work. And now first focus on edtiText.

Comment: @IljaBulatov what's your listView item views made up of?

Comment: I added list view item xml in main post.

About your update, maybe I can force set focus on ListView ?

Comment: no, as you said that removing the `focusableInTouchMode="true"` didn't help, I don't think the problem is related to focus.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

and

`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

from parent layout.

Read about [android:descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability):

> beforeDescendants:    The ViewGroup will get focus before any of its
>   descendants.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! But still doesn't work. And now first focus on edtiText.

Comment: Have you implement some listeners to your ListView (java code) ?

Comment: Sorry for my printing.
Yes, i have onitemclicklistner:


eventListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UIEventDetalizationActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

Comment: Can you post your list item xml file?

Comment: Update Answer with list item xml